# Using JavaScript to send input to a url and control a iframe until submit?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, input, submit-button

I have a basic html setup:

```
        <input id="input_data" type="text" />
    <input id="submit_data" type="submit" value="submit" />
<br />
<iframe name="Frame1" id="Frame1" src="~/d/Test.php?DataId=(This is where I need input data)" ></iframe>
```

I've looked over some similar titles and the methods didn't work. Prehaps I'm doing something wrong completely as the iframe shouldn't even do anything until submit is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `form` tag for submit and use return for prevent the page refresh .And set the [**`src`**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHg4PviJfUAhUIuI8KHczKAgoQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fprop_frame_src.asp&usg=AFQjCNEstGhwyjDiMnBI_gADs5DkvyEd_g&sig2=rj_BR-HLQCvuh1Dh8nHduA) attribute via dom .The iframe was loaded after the src added

```js
function add() {
  var url = document.getElementById('input_data').value
  document.getElementById('Frame1').src = "~/d/Test.php?DataId=" + url
  console.log(document.getElementById('Frame1').src);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return add()">
  <input id="input_data" type="text" />
  <input id="submit_data" type="submit" value="submit" />
  <br />
</form>
<iframe name="Frame1" id="Frame1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The iFrame is being loaded as soon as the parent page is rendered, because you set the src attribute within the html tag.

If you wish to load it later you can do so by setting the src attribute in JavaScript then:

```
document.getElementById("Frame1").src = "/d/Test.php?DataId=" + data;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, was way over doing it and trying to pass it around as a string without any scripts. Late night.

Comment: Glad I could help.